# Multiple Generics: Best Common superclass

Tags: java, generics

I am building a ListUtil list merge implementation. The idea is two feed a method two arbitrary Lists, and for it to give back a list typed with the closest common superclass of the initial list types. Is this even possible in java?

Comment: Why wouldn't returning a generic `List` work?  What benefit are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
private static <T> List<T> getSuper(List<? extends T> one, List<? extends T> two) {
    List<T> ts = new ArrayList<>(one);
    ts.addAll(two);
    return ts;
}
```

Used e.g. via:

```
List<Integer> one = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> two = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> aSuper = getSuper(one, two);
```

Comment: I think the idea was that if one and two are LinkedLists, then a LinkedList is returned. It's not completely clear though.

Comment: This is remarkably a lot simpler than I imagined! Thanks!

Comment: @assylias hmm, I did not even think about that.

Comment: I'm not sure how this even attempts to answer the question asked.  It returns a list, but doesn't even try to match the types of the lists inputted

Comment: @phflack because you misunderstand the question ;) Not the List itself is the generic, OP was asking about the generic contents of the lists.

Comment: @luk2302 Ooooh - the closest supertype of T, not ArrayList or whatever... :-)

Comment: @assylias It seems so, we both thought in opposite directions. To be honest after understanding your solution it becomes clear that the question was not 100% precise. I got lucky and thought in the "right" direction.

Comment: Should probably edit the question to ask that specifically, as current it is not asking that

Comment: @WeckarE. you may want to include the example I have shown in my answer into the question to make clear what you were trying to achieve in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a strong reason to do that I would suggest two alternatives:

1. Return a list of any type you want (`ArrayList` is probably a reasonable default candidate), but don't show it to the user:

   ```
   static <T> List<T> merge(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
   ```
2. let the user decide what type of list he/she wants:

   ```
   static <T, L extends List<T>> L merge(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Supplier<L> listSupplier)
   ```

With the latter, you can call the method with, for example:

```
merge(list1, list2, LinkedList::new);
```